# Can you describe a table without using a database?

Tags: mysql

I only have read access to a database and am getting the following back from trying to do `USE dbname`:

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names 
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

So I wanted to know if as a workaround I could `DESCRIBE` a table within `dbname` without having to do `USE dbname`, as I believe other tables in the database are forbidden to me? My aim is to only find out the tables columns so I can make a replicate in my development environment

Comment: I can describe a table... with adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `tabelname`;
```

Comment: ? what does that do? seems suspicious (no offense)

Comment: it returns the sql to create table

Comment: I see, but my problem is that I get the above mentioned error when I try to 'USE' the database and therefore can't run the 'USE' statement. I was wondering if there is a way to bypass the 'USE' statement to describe the table within the database?

Comment: cant you just SHOW tablename?

Comment: do you have access to data folder? this can help http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/01/02/recover-table-structure-frm-files-mysql-utilities/

Comment: @JohnRuddell I tried, but apparently you need to be using the database first

Comment: seems I don't know where the .frm files are kept. i will try and write a script to describe the table

Comment: in `mysql` folder you should have `data` folder ... in `data` every database should have it's own folder